# Parse image that i am receiving from web service . Its a stream object. How can i retrieve that in android?

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, android-studio, android-glide

When i call the web service in android it fetches the image but as the image is stream object glide doesnt process it.

Here is my code of web service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace ImageTransferService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Stream GetImage(int i)
        {
            if (i == 5)
            {
                FileStream imageFilePath = File.OpenRead(@"E:\Images\h1.jpg");
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                return imageFilePath;

            }
            else
                return null;

        }


    }
}
```

**Service**

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace ImageTransferService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        Stream GetImage(int i);

    }
  }
```

**My android code:**

```
package com.example.unais.myapplication;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
 * Created by Unais on 7/26/2016.
 */
public class WebService {

    private final static String URL = "http://192.168.1.21:1313/Service1.svc/";
    private static final String REGISTER_METHOD = "GetImage";


    public InputStream CallService(String methodName, JSONStringer json) {

        try {


            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL + methodName);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            request.setEntity(entity);

            // Send request to WCF service
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            return stream;

//            // Read response data into buffer
//            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
//
//            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//            String line = null;
//            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                sb.append(line + "\n");
//            }
//            stream.close();

//            Log.d("asgasgasgasgaga", sb.toString());
//            return sb.toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.d("Exception", "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Exception", "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }



    public InputStream GetImages()
    {
        Log.d("Function","In Function Get Images");
        try
        {
            JSONStringer registerJson = new JSONStringer()
                    .object()
                    .key("i").value(5)
                    .endObject();

            return (CallService(REGISTER_METHOD, registerJson));
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
     }
   }
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
        {

            Image image = images.get(position);



            Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getIota())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);
        }
```

If you want other code i can provide.I am stucked on this so please help me :/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is load image see this example load image in

> Uri.parse(xxx)

```
String assetPath = "file:///android_asset/flags/FR.jpg";
Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(Uri.parse(assetPath))
            .placeholder(missingFlagDrawable)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .into(flag);
```

Refer this link [Load image in Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/155)